# Add Datas to different two tables with using same view and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add datas to two different tables using same view and controller. But I am stuck. I am new at MVC, please let me know what did I wrong.Dto Model, Controller, Facade, Servicei,View and Entity Model as follows.
I get this Error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'LibOrganizerEntity.Entity.OrgProje', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'LibOrganizerSvc.Dto.ProjeEkleDto'.

Entity Models

```
[Table("KAR_PROJE")]
public class OrgProje
{
    [Key, Required]
    [Column("SIRA_NO")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("ACIKLAMA")]
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }

    [Column("PLANLANAN_BASLANGIC_TARIHI")]
    public DateTime? PlanlananBaslangicTarihi { get; set; }

    [Column("PLANLANAN_BITIS_TARIHI")]
    public DateTime? PlanlananBitisTarihi { get; set; }

    [Column("GERCEKLESEN_BASLANGIC_TARIHI")]
    public DateTime? GerceklesenBaslangicTarihi { get; set; }

    [Column("GERCEKLESEN_BITIS_TARIHI")]
    public DateTime? GerceklesenBitisTarihi { get; set; }

    [Column("SILINME_TARIHI")]
    public DateTime? SilinmeTarihi { get; set; }

    [Column("YONETICI_ID")]
    public int? YoneticiId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("YoneticiId")]

    public virtual OrgPersonel OrgPersonel { get; set; }
    public virtual OrgProjeButce OrgProjeButce { get; set; }
    public virtual OrgButce Butce { get; set; }

}

[Table("KAR_PROJE_BUTCE")]
public class OrgProjeButce
{
    [Key, Required]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("BUTCE_ID")]
    public int ButceId { get; set; }

    [Column("BUTCE_TUTAR")]
    public float ButceTutar { get; set; }

    [Column("GERCEKLESEN")]
    public float? Gerceklesen { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ButceId")]
    public virtual OrgButce OrgButce { get; set; }


}
```

Dto Model

```
public class ProjeEkleDto
{

    public string Aciklama { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PlanlananBaslangicTarihi { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PlanlananBitisTarihi { get; set; }
    public DateTime? GerceklesenBaslangicTarihi { get; set; }
    public DateTime? GerceklesenBitisTarihi { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SilinmeTarihi { get; set; }
    public string YoneticiAdi { get; set; }
    public string YoneticiSoyadi { get; set; }
    public string YoneticiId { get; set; }
    public int ButceId { get; set; }
    public string ButceAdi { get; set; }
    public float ProjeButceTutari { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<OrgPersonel> Proje { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<OrgProjeButce> Butce { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ProjeEkle()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProjeEkle(OrgProje model)
    {
        try
        {

            svc.ProjeEkle(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Service

```
public void ProjeEkle(OrgProje proje)
    {
        var dto = new ProjeFacade(db);
        dto.ProjeEkle(proje);
    }
```

Facade

```
public void ProjeEkle(OrgProje proje)
    {
        db.OrgProjeler.Add(proje);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

View

```
@model LibOrganizerSvc.Dto.ProjeEkleDto
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ProjeEkle";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Proje Ekle</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <h4 class="heading_a">Proje Detayları</h4>

                        <div class="form-group" style="width: 47%; float: left">
                            <label for="reg_input">Proje Adı</label>
                            <input type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.Aciklama)" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="width: 47%; float: right;">
                            <label for="reg_input">Proje Yöneticisi</label>
                            <select id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.YoneticiId)" name="chn_country" class="form-control">
                                @Html.Action("_PersonelleriGetir", "Ortak")
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="width: 47%; float: right;">
                            <label for="reg_input">Proje Bütçe Türleri</label>

                            <select id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.ButceAdi)" name="@Html.IdFor(x => x.ButceAdi)" class="form-control">
                                @Html.Action("_ButceleriGetir", "Ortak")
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
                            <label for="reg_input">Proje Bütçesi</label>
                            <input type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.ProjeButceTutari)" class="form-control" name="@Html.IdFor(x => x.ProjeButceTutari)">
                            <span class="help-block">2000 &#x20BA;</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h4 class="heading_a">Proje Zaman Ayarları</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <label for="reg_input">Planlanan Başlama Tarihi</label>
                        <div class="input-group date ebro_datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.PlanlananBaslangicTarihi)">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <label for="reg_input">Planlanan Bitiş Tarihi</label>
                        <div class="input-group date ebro_datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.PlanlananBitisTarihi)">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <label for="reg_input" style="margin-top: 15px;">Gerçekleşen Başlama Tarihi</label>
                        <div class="input-group date ebro_datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.GerceklesenBaslangicTarihi)">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <label for="reg_input" style="margin-top: 15px;">Gerçekleşen Bitiş Tarihi</label>
                        <div class="input-group date ebro_datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.GerceklesenBitisTarihi)">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; margin-top: 20px; width: 90%; position: relative; left: 15px;">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Kaydet" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you are passing a class of type `OrgProje` to a view that requires a view of type `ProjeEkleDto`.

Your error occurs in this action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProjeEkle(OrgProje model)
{
    try
    {
        svc.ProjeEkle(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { 

    }

    return View(model); // Passing a view model of the wrong type to the view
}
```

Either pass a view model of type `ProjeEkleDto` back to the view instead of your model of type `OrgProje`, or create a different view that accepts a view model of type `OrgProje`.

Comment: Yes you're right but there is one more problem on this controller. (OrgProje model) is comin null to the controller from the view after I posted the form. So this method only runs catch and return View(model) parts.

Comment: I felt bad when I solve the problem. I forgot add name attribute to the inputs. But you're right HTX9 thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your view Change -

```
@model LibOrganizerSvc.Dto.ProjeEkleDto
```

to

```
@model NameSpace.ProjeEkleDto
```

I am not sure about which namespace to be used, but you replace `NameSpace` with appropriate one.

Comment: NameSpace is "LibOrganizerSvc.Dto"